# How to fork several children to simultaneously compute several timesteps of a dynamical process

Tags: c, algorithm, math, fork, physics

I think the answer is "it can't be done", but I don't want to program the project without exhausting all possibilities. Here's more detail...

I've already successfully programmed a simulation whose output is an animated gif, where the frames display the simulated system's configuration timestep after timestep. But in this successful case, timesteps can be computed independently, i.e., there's a closed-form solution so that I don't need the result of timestep **t** to compute the result for **t+dt**, etc. So I fork several, say ***n***, child processes for **t,t+dt,t+2dt,...,t+(*n-1*)dt**, wait for them all to finish, and then assemble the gif frames in time-order. Works fine.

But in this new case, the dynamical system's more complicated, and timestep **t+dt** can't be computed without first numerically computing timestep **t**. That is, there's no closed-form solution. So it seems to me the problem's non-parallelizable, and there's no significant way to make use of multiple cores. (I could fork a child to assemble the gif frame for timestep **t** while **t+dt** is computing, but that's insignificant.) Am I hopefully wrong about that? Is there any useful way to utilize multiple cores in this kind of situation?

Comment: You gave the answer yourself: "timestep t+dt can't be computed without first numerically computing timestep t". So you have to do it sequentially.

Comment: @Henry okay, thanks (for nothing:). This kind of problem/situation obviously arises quite often, whereby I figured people have given lots of thought about how to possibly take advantage of all those otherwise-idle cores. So if there's any clever/tricky/whatever way to do that, then I wasn't seeing it, but somebody's probably already figured it out.

Comment: However, if you have a multi-body problem where the computation for each body depends on the same iterative solution for a given `t + dt`, (e.g. tracking multiple satellites, etc..) you can either fork multiple processes to solve for each body, or use threads to accomplish the same thing. In that case you can make use of multiple cores to speed the solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, that'll work, I think (and I think I probably should have thought of that myself:). It's indeed a many-(many-)body problem, where I should be able to fork a child for each body, to calculate the pairwise interactions between it and all others. (That'll redundantly calculate the symmetrical **i<-->j** interaction twice, but a very small price to pay.)  Thanks, again (and feel free to post it as an answer if you want another +15 to add to your 35K. P.S. okay, I'm confused -- you're a lawyer with 612pts on law and 35K on stackoverflow?:)

Comment: Yes, in any simulation type problem, where `t` is your independent variable and all other calculations depend on the timestep, you can fork or create multiple threads to handle the calculation for each body for each timestep. This will dramatically help. (if you use threads, don't create more threads than you have cores or you lose the benefit of parallel processing by creating additional scheduling problems as threads wait for a core). Will let the comment pass the idea. This is more a program design issue rather than a coding error/problem. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simulated time dependent physical processes before and I know it is desirable to speed up the process as much as you can. Although the inter-dependency of each time step makes parallelization difficult, if not impossible, you can still try to parallel some of the computations within each time step.

- Do you have loops in the algorithm of each time step that can be parallelized?
- If no loops, can the calculations within each time step be separated into sections that can go independently? You can then ask different cores to do these things simultaneously.
- If you have different parameters / settings to try out (usually for publishing academic papers, some parameter sweep is desirable to generate a plot), can you parallelize on these parameters? The time dependence will be out of the picture in this way.
- Do you have array / matrix operations that you can potentially speed up using some SIMD features of your CPU (this is in addition to the use of multiple cores), if not already handled by libraries specialized in doing so?